# Updating a cell in Google Sheets based on whether the value appears on two different tabs in the same workbook

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I am trying to make a cell in my "Inventory" sheet update to "Yes" if that item appears on either of two other sheets in the workbook. If the item from column B does not appear in either sheet, the cell should read "No".

If I use the following formula to check my "2023 Completed" sheet, I do get a proper yes/no result.

```
=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP($B$2:$B$200, '2023 Completed'!$D$2:$D$100, 1, FALSE)), "No", "Yes")
```

I am trying to check both the '2023 Completed' and '2024 Completed' sheets though. I have tried many variations of formulas and just get a parsing error no matter what I try. The most recent formula I have is:

```
=IF(OR(ISERROR(VLOOKUP($B$2:$B$200, '2023 Completed'!$D$2:$D$100, 1, FALSE)), "No", "Yes"), (ISERROR(VLOOKUP($B$2:$B$200, '2024 Completed'!$C$2:$C$100, 1, FALSE)), "No", "Yes"))
```

The shift from column D to column C is correct, I removed a column between the two years' sheets. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here - any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

*Try this slightly modified formula of yours:*

```js
=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP($B$2:$B$200, {'2023 Completed'!$D$2:$D$100;'2024 Completed'!$C$2:$C$100}, 1, FALSE)), "No", "Yes")
```